# You are trying to add a non-nullable field (id)... when trying to makemigrations

Tags: django

Here's what's happened:

1. I created the following models:

   class Workout(models.Model):

   ```
   datetime = models.DateTimeField()
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   lifts = fields.LiftsField()
   cardio = JSONField()

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.datetime)+" "+self.user.email

   __repr__ = __str__
   ```

   class Activity(models.Model):

   ```
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
   __repr__ = __str__
   ```

   class CardioActivity(Activity):
       pass

   class LiftActivity(Activity):
       pass
2. I ran `makemigrations` and `migrate`

   `workoutcal/migrations/0002_activity_cardioactivity_liftactivity_workout.py
           - Create model Activity
           - Create model Workout
           - Create model CardioActivity
           - Create model LiftActivity`

**0002_activity_cardioactivity_liftactivity_workout.py**

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('workoutcal', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Activity',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Workout',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('datetime', models.DateTimeField()),
                ('lifts', workoutcal.fields.LiftsField()),
                ('cardio', django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb.JSONField()),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='CardioActivity',
            fields=[
                ('activity_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='workoutcal.Activity')),
            ],
            bases=('workoutcal.activity',),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='LiftActivity',
            fields=[
                ('activity_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='workoutcal.Activity')),
            ],
            bases=('workoutcal.activity',),
        ),
    ]
```

3. Then I turned the `Activity` class into a meta class:

   class Activity(models.Model):

   ```
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
   __repr__ = __str__

   class Meta:
       abstract = True
   ```
4. And tried to `makemigrations` again:

   `(workout) Sahands-MBP:workout sahandzarrinkoub$ python manage.py makemigrations
   You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to cardioactivity without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
   Please select a fix:
    1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
    2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py`

What is the reason for this message? It doesn't make any sense to me. `CardioActivity` hasn't even been changed since the last migration, how can it complain about me trying to add an `id` field??

EDIT: What's in the database?

When I check the `CardioActivity` table in the database, here's what I find:

```
workout=# \dt
                     List of relations
 Schema |               Name               | Type  | Owner 
--------+----------------------------------+-------+-------
 public | auth_group                       | table | admin
 public | auth_group_permissions           | table | admin
 public | auth_permission                  | table | admin
 public | django_admin_log                 | table | admin
 public | django_content_type              | table | admin
 public | django_migrations                | table | admin
 public | django_session                   | table | admin
 public | workoutcal_activity              | table | admin
 public | workoutcal_cardioactivity        | table | admin
 public | workoutcal_liftactivity          | table | admin
 public | workoutcal_user                  | table | admin
 public | workoutcal_user_groups           | table | admin
 public | workoutcal_user_user_permissions | table | admin
 public | workoutcal_workout               | table | admin
(14 rows)

workout=# SELECT * FROM workoutcal_cardioactivity;
 activity_ptr_id 
-----------------
(0 rows)
```

As you can see, there aren't even any existing rows in the table! How can Django then say that it needs to populate existing rows??

Answer (score 0):

Django makemigration doesn't check if there are any records in the table. So if you add new field to model it must have default value or you must add null=True for that field